# How to Select Window in headless mode?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

I want to test if a Print popup appeared using Robot Framework.

```
Test Print Popup Appeared
    Click Element    class:print_button
    Get Window Handles    # 2 windows in normal mode, 1 window in headless
    Select Window    NEW
    Page Should Contain Element    //button[@class='print default']
    Click Element    class:cancel
    Select Window    MAIN
```

If I do not use headless mode test is OK. 
But in headless mode it fails.

> FAIL: Window with last index is same as the current window.

Is there any possibility to operate with popups in headless mode?
Thanks.

---

UPD. As I can see serfing on this problem Chrome disables popups in headless mode. The same problem occurs when I'm trying to download files: OK in normal mode, FAIL in headless.

I tried to start browser with custom option `disable-popup-blocking` but did not succeed, the problem remains.

```
Test Suit Setup
    ${options} =    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys,selenium.webdriver
    Call Method    ${options}    add_argument    headless
    Call Method    ${options}    add_argument    disable-popup-blocking
    Create WebDriver    Chrome    chrome_options=${options}
```

Comment: Can you `Get Window Handles` before `Click Element class:cancel`. That gives idea, how many windows does exist.

Comment: Remember that when running in headless mode, it may be faster, so the window is not ready yet. Try to add a delay to see if that is the case.

Comment: @supputuri When in normal mode there are 2 opened windows: main and print popup. When in headless - just one main window

Comment: @Helio Thank you. There is actually some delay, so that's not the case

Comment: Cool. It's always better to use `Get Window Handles` when you are using Headless at least, how many windows does exist at the point when you try to switch.